# C# WCF communication with client certificate

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, security, ssl

i am developing very simple desktop (win forms) application, that comunicates with server via WCF service on HTTPS protocol.
Every client that use this application, can upload client certificate (unique for each client), wich shall be used to to communication.

What exactly i am trying to achieve: 
1. user will "upload" certificate to my desktop application, application take the certificate and programmatically save the certificate to windows cert store, here is my code:

```
[SecurityCritical]
public CertificateInfoDto GetCertificateInfoAndImportToStore(string fullPath, SecureString password)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fullPath))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("fullPath");
        }

        if (!File.Exists(fullPath))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Concat("No file present on ", fullPath));
        }

        try
        {
            byte[] rawBytes = this.GetCertificateContent(fullPath);
            var certificate = new X509Certificate2(rawBytes, password, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
            this.EnsureImport(certificate);
         }
   // some error handling etc, and end of method.


[SecurityCritical]
private void EnsureImport(X509Certificate2 certificate)
{
   X509Store store = null;
   try
   {
      store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
      store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
      store.Add(certificate);
   }
```

In my application settings file, i store only certificate serial number.
2. Now, when i have uploaded certificate to windows store, i want to use it for wcf communication, so my code looks like:

```
var client = new SomeWcfServiceProxy();
client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(
            StoreLocation.CurrentUser,
            StoreName.My,
            X509FindType.FindBySerialNumber,
            certificateSerialNumber);
```

And finally, here is my problem, when i try to call some method on proxy, ill get an exception: 
System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException: Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority 'url (i changed this)'. ---> System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

But what confuses me, is that when i create proxy client like this:

```
var client = new SomeWcfServiceProxy();
var clientCertificate = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\U\BB\certificate.pfx", "password");
client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = clientCertificate;
```

Everything working like a charm! 
So there is my question: I do not want to store clients certificate password anywhere, i want to once upload it via windows certificate store and then use it only from windows certificate store. Is this possible? Or i must store certificate password somewhere ( i do not know where, becouse i think it is not very secure and this certificates are very very confidential).
Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Maybe your user does not have permissions to private key of the certificate.
Check in mmc console if the user that runs the process have read access to private key.

Comment: Grzegorz it looks like you saved my life. It looks like this was exactly my issue! :) Ill test it and write if it will work! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all, i needed this:

```
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(rawBytes, password, X509KeyStorageFlags.UserKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
```

Now certificate is imported just right and can be used for communication without any problems